# Erase specific element from a vector is not working

Tags: c++, vector

```
// erasing from vector
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  // set some values (from 1 to 10)
  for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

  //First for loop
  for(int i=myvector.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
      myvector.erase(myvector.begin()+i);
  }

  //second for loop which isn't working 

//   for(int i=0;i<myvector.size();i++)
//   {
//       myvector.erase(myvector.begin()+i);
//   }



  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<myvector.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

In this code I have two for loops doing the exact same thing.  The first one is working while the second one which is commented isn't,
and the output if I used the commented for loop is:

```
myvector contains: 2 4 6 8 10
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: don't increment the i variable in the second for loop

Answer (score 4):

It is because in the condition you call `myvector.size()` which will return smaller and smaller number since your vector is shrinking by each iteration.

In the first version you only call it once to initialize `i` that is why there is no problem. But in the second version it is called in each iteration.

Comment: Calling `vector.size()` just once would be even worse in the second loop since it would loop to what the old size was, causing undefined behavior. The problem isn't the number of times `size()` is called, it's that each erase shifts all elements down one. On the first iteration the 0th element is erased, and the 1st element becomes the new 0th element. On the second iteration, the new 1st element is erased (which is the old 2nd element), skipping the new 0th element. Etc. Leapfrogging over every other element.

Comment: @John that should be posted as an answer

Comment: Yes it also should be also something like `myvector.erase(myvector.begin())` this only.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) removes the element(s) in the given range `[first, last)` or at the given position (the version you're using), and calls the assignment operator for every element after the removed element to "shift it down".

Consider the `std::vector` that looks like this to start:

```
[ a0 | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 | a6 ]
```

On your first loop iteration, you erase the element in the vector at position 0, which transforms the vector in this way:

```
[ a0 | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 | a6 ] --> [ a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 | a6 ]
  ^
  |
  erase at position 0
```

On your second loop iteration, you erase the element in the vector at position 1, which transforms the vector this way:

```
[ a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 | a6 ] --> [ a1 | a3 | a4 | a5 | a6 ]
       ^
       |
       erase at position 1
```

Notice that we've "skipped over" element `a1`, which was originally at position 1 in the vector.

Because each loop iteration is a combination of:

1. Erasing an element (shifting everything above it down), and
2. Incrementing our index

We will skip over every element until we reach the end (or beyond).

---

If you want to erase every element in the `std::vector`, you have several options.

You can adjust your loop variable whenever you find an element to erase. Since all elements are shifted down by one, you want to shift your loop variable down by one *if* you erase something.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); ++i)
{
    myvector.erase(myvector.begin() + i);
    // if we erased an element, decrement the loop variable
    --i;
}
```

If you know the range of elements you want to `erase`, you can call `erase` on that range:

```
myvector.erase(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
```

If you want to `erase` all element in the `vector`, you can call `clear`.

```
myvector.clear();
```

If you want to erase all elements that match a certain search criteria, you can use the `remove`-`erase` idiom. We use `remove` to move all elements that match a (removal) criteria to the end of the container (but doesn't actually remove them - intuitive, I know) `remove` returns an iterator to the start of these "removed" elements. You then call `erase` on the range of this returned iterator to the end of the old container.

```
// This will remove/erase all elements in the vector that are greater than 5
myvector.erase(std::remove_if(myvector.begin(), 
                              myvector.end(),
                              [](int x){return x > 5;}),
               myvector.end());
```